# Getting value from Textbox created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a textbox using JavaScript

```
var textInput = document.createElement("input");
```

Now I want to get text from that textfield in JavaScript.

How can I get it?

i have tried with defining **Input.id = 'inp'** and **var get = document.querySelector("#inp").value;** but cant get solution.

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: yes i have tried
with defining **Input.id = 'inp'** and 
**var get = document.querySelector("#inp").value;**
but cant get solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: @HamzaAwan Why don't you show us what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoveXXxrflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: @HamzaAwan We need a [mcve].  It's not possible to help you based on the limited information we have.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one key piece in creating HTML elements with JS. The code you have creates the element, but it's not actually being placed into the document.

```
document.body.appendChild(textInput);
```

This will actually insert the created element into the body. You then should be able to access it's contents.